# Why does my Umbraco installation from within the Azure Marketplace always fail?

Tags: azure, umbraco, azure-web-app-service, azure-marketplace

I am trying to install Umbraco by using the Azure Marketplace. There they offer a template for it. I am always receiving the error below. I tried to install it a couple of times now but I always get the same error.

Does anybody know what this error message means? Is anybody able to install Umbraco by using the template in the Azure Marketplace?

[image: My start point from within Azure]
[image: Deployment List]
[image]
[image: appManagerStatus.xml]]

Comment: Based on my understanding, it fails when it's trying to deploy the web deploy package for Umbraco via MSDeploy. Have you try different location or create a support ticket to Microsoft?

Comment: I tried several locations. Maybe you are right and I should create a support ticket.

Comment: I have provided a more detailed answer on your questions with the detailed troubleshooting steps. Let me know if it is helpful and if you need extra help.

Comment: FYI, I just encountered this error when trying the deployment in the North Europe DC, but got it working OK in West Europe.

Comment: Interesting. I have the issue in the West Europe DC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Microsoft employee confirmed [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/58342f16-e8a5-4cb1-bdea-996517384f7b/why-does-my-umbraco-installation-from-within-the-azure-marketplace-always-fail?forum=DataMarket) is a bug in the application currently. I have to wait for a fix.

Comment: Hi Philipp, I believe this issue has recently been fixed. You should be able the create Umbraco CMS from the portal.

Answer (score 2):

You're asking 2 questions above.

Please see my answers and proposed troubleshooting guide/workaround below:

1. The error message means that the **MSDeploy** process failed due to some error which renders it unable to deploy the **web deploy package** for your Umbraco web app.
2. Yes I am able to provision a Umbraco web app from the Azure Market successfully (Location: Central US) and couldn't reproduce your issue

**Troubleshooting Guide:**

1. Append **.scm** in front of the azurewebsites.net of your Umbraco Web App as shown below and go to the Url. 
   [image]
2. Click on the Diagnostic Dump. You will be prompted to download a **.zip** file
   [image]
3. Extract the zip file. You should see 2 folders at root level
   [image]
4. Go into

> LogFiles\SiteExtensions\MSDeploy

You should see the detail log files for MSDeploy
[image]

5. Detailed MSDeploy log messages are in the **appManagerLog.xml** file.
6. If it is related to client side issue which can be resolved by yourself, you can try to resolve it and try again.

If it is related to server side issue, you should create a support ticket for Microsoft to look into with the detailed MSDeploy log which pinpoints the root cause which will help them a lot.

Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thanks. I have added the content of appManagerStatus.xml. Unfortunately it does not bring much help as you can see in the screen shot. I think I will try to contact the Azure support. But thanks anyway.

Comment: Sure, that's the best we can did from our end. If you think it's helpful anyway please kindly acknowledge, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered numerous problems with the Azure installer of Umbraco, try setting it up in VS2015 then publishing it to Azure. I have found that this works well.